# How would I create txt files in each folder within a directory using a Bat file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that creates a text document ("subfoldername".txt) inside each directory's subfolder.

```
| Parent Folder:

|--Subfolder 1
|----image01
|----image02
|----image03

|--Subfolder 2
|----image01
|----image02
|----image03
```

and what I want to do is:

```
| Parent Folder:

|--Subfolder 1
|----image01
|----image02
|----image03
|----"Subfolder 1".txt

|--Subfolder 2
|----image01
|----image02
|----image03
|----"Subfolder 2".txt
```

Where the newly created text file lists the images in each of the subfolders.

What I have is:

```
@echo off
for /r %%g in (*) do (
    for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
        @echo file '%%i' >> list.txt
        )
    )
```

I know that `for %%i in (*.jpg) do (@echo file '%%i' >> list.txt)` works within one folder (haven't figured out the how to name it the subfolder name yet) , but I want to be able to run this command for each folder within a directory.

But when I run the code, no text file is created.

Comment: You need a `for /d` loop (see `for /?` for details). If you need it recursive (also in sub-sub-...-folders), use `for /r /d` (not documented, but working fine)

Comment: I've tried `for /d` `for /r /d` and `for /r` and none of them created a txt file in the subfolders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you were looking for was a `For /D` loop with a standard nested `For` loop:

```bat
@For /D %%I In ("Parent Folder\*")Do @(For %%J In ("%%I\*.jpg")Do @Echo %%~nxJ)>"%%I\%%~nxI.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I see that you already have an answer. Yes, Compo does some most excellent work and I am sure it will work for you.

Some day, someone might need to maintain or modify this script. Finding someone who understands all of the `%%~...` cryptology might not be easy. It might be easier to find someone who knows PowerShell; Microsoft's stated strategy for the future. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
$baseDir = 'C:/src/t'
$filenamePattern = '*.jpg'

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $baseDir |
    ForEach-Object {
        $newFile = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.txt')
        if (Test-Path -Path $newFile) { Remove-item -Path $newFile }
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter $filenamePattern |
            ForEach-Object {
                $_.Name | Out-File -FilePath $newFile -Append -WhatIf
            }
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that a supported Windows system, must be carrying at least PowerShell v3.0 for the code above. That means by default, it requires Windows 8 / Server 2012, unless the PC has been specifically updated to include it, _(and even then it would need to be minimum Windows 7 SP1 / Server 2008 SP2 / Server 2008 R2 SP1)_. Also you'd need to reconfigure your system to allow the running of PowerShell scripts, which are disabled by default, or run powershell.exe from cmd.exe with the script as an argument and an appropriate execution policy option._

Comment: @Compo - You are exactly right, as usual. Windows 7 and Server 2008 still have 15 days until EOL (End of Life). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057281/windows-7-support-will-end-on-january-14-2020 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2008 Organizations need to be setting a PowerShell policy and configuring their machines.